# OUTPUT my Fetched Data to my Main Program in PHP OOP

Tags: php

I'm a newbie in PHP OOP. Can you please help me how to fix this code below because it gives me an infinite output. I want to output or echo my fetched data to my main program. Thanks.

===========================================

```
class DB {

private $_hostdb = 'localhost';
private $_namedb = 'imsdb';
private $_userdb = 'root';
private $_passdb = '';
private $_conn;
private static $_instance;
private $_rowResult;

private function __construct(){
try{
    $this->_conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$this->_hostdb;dbname=$this-    >_namedb",$this->_userdb,$this->_passdb);
    $this->_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

         if($this->_conn){
             echo "Connected Successfully!";
         }

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo ("Connection Failed!")."".$ex->getMessage();
    } 
}

public static function getInstance(){
     if(!isset(self::$_instance))
     {
          return self::$_instance=new DB();
     }
}

public function processQuery($sql){
try{

     $q=$this->_conn->prepare($sql);
     $q->execute();
     $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     return $this->_rowResult=$q->fetch(); //Is this correct??

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
           echo ("Failed!")." ".$ex->getMessage();
    }
  }
}

//MAIN PROGRAM -> OUTPUT gives me an infinite data which is wrong

 $dbUser=DB::getInstance()->processQuery("SELECT * FROM users");

while($dbUser){
    echo $dbUser['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is infinite because it keeps processing $dbUser which returns true each time, it's equivalent to saying `while(true)`

You really want to access the result set via a getter method, so in your class you could add something like:

```
public function getResultSet() {
    return $this->_rowResult;
}
```

I've edited this and modified the bits you have listed:

```
class DB {

    ...
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance; // Always return your instance, the if statement just sets it in the property if it's not already
    }

    public function processQuery($sql)
    {
        try {
            $q = $this->_conn->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute();
            $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this->rowResult = $q->fetchAll(); // Use fetchAll rather than fetch
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo "Failed!", "<br />", $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And your main program:

```
//MAIN PROGRAM
$dbUser = DB::getInstance();
$user = $dbUser->processQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
foreach ($dbUser->getResultSet() as $user) {
    print_r($user['id']);
}
```

Comment: It gives me now this error after following your suggestion.  Fatal error: Call to a member function getResultSet()

Comment: You need an object instance to call that, try:

`$dbUser = DB::getInstance();
$dbUser->processQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
while ($dbUser->getResultSet()) { ... }`

Also in your static getInstance you'll want to return the $_instance property always:

`public static function getInstance(){
     if(!isset(self::$_instance))
     {
          self::$_instance=new DB();
     }
    return self::$_instance;
}`

Comment: It tried the code below but it gives me one row record but it repeats 7 times..something is not right with my main program

Answer (score 1):

```
  It tried code below but it gives me one record and it repeats 7 times.
   OUTPUT: 1111111
   ===================================
   class DB {

   private $_hostdb = 'localhost';
   private $_namedb = 'imsdb';
   private $_userdb = 'root';
   private $_passdb = '';
   private $_conn;
   private static $_instance; //must be static
   public $rowResult;


   private function __construct(){
       try{
        $this->_conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$this->_hostdb;dbname=$this-     >_namedb",$this->_userdb,$this->_passdb);
        $this->_conn-   >setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        if($this->_conn){
            echo "Connected Successfully!<br />";
        }
        //
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
           echo ("Connection Failed!")."<br />".$ex->getMessage();
        }     
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance))
    {
        return self::$_instance=new DB();
    }
    }

    public function processQuery($sql){
    try{

       $q=$this->_conn->prepare($sql);
       $q->execute();
       $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       return $this->rowResult=$q->fetch();

      } catch (Exception $ex) {
       return ("Failed!")."<br />".$ex->getMessage();
      }
      }

      public function getResultSet(){
      return $this->rowResult;
      }
      }
      //MAIN PROGRAM
      $dbUser=DB::getInstance();
      $user=$dbUser->processQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
      for($i=0;$i<count($dbUser->rowResult);$i++){
             echo $user['id'];
      }
```